# How to refer to a class on one page on an event in another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**header.html**

```
  <div>
     <a href="#" id="reports">reports</a>
     <a href="#" id="summary">reports</a>
  </div>
```

**detailpage.html**

```
  <object src="header.html">
  </object>
  <section>
     <div class="abc"></div>
     <div class="123"></div>
  </section>
```

`header.html` is imported in `detailpage.html`, on the click of the reports tab in `header.html` div with class `abc` should be displayed and on the click of the summary tab in `header.html` div with class `123` should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply listen to click events on the two divs in header.html, and then show the two other divs :

```
//Hide them if necessary
//$(".abc").hide();
//$(".123").hide();

$("#reports").click(function(){
  $(".abc").show();
});

$("#summary").click(function(){
  $(".123").show();
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WSHh2/) to demonstrate the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){
    $('#reports').click(function(){
        if($('.abc').is(':visible'))
           $('.abc').hide();
        else
          $('.abc').show();
     });

    $('#summary').click(function(){
       if($('.123').is(':visible'))
         $('.123').hide();
       else
         $('.123').show();
    });

});
```

*Note : you can hide your divs on page load*